# spring - prevent destroying session on auto logout

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a java spring mvc project. I need to store some data in session in this way:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("data", "someData");
```

This works correctly and I can get session data somewhere else in the project. But when the spring sessions times out and user redirects to login page, the above session clears and I cant access `data` session after spring auto logout. Could anyone explain me where is the problem?

After auto logout, `request.getSession(true).getAttribute("data")` returns null.

**In fact, I want to access session attributes after spring auto logout.**

Note, I'm using java config instead of xml config for my spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If a [http session](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) timed out you cannot access the session anymore. That has nothing to do with Spring Security, it is part of the [Servlet API specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1446667712_a49ce99074a747e81b83c67534d22def):

> Once the session 
>   invalidation is initiated, a new request 
>   must not be able to see that session.